# Runtime Error Unfortunately app has stopped please give me solution

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I am working on this app which is nearbyplaces when i run my app it give no error but in run time it give  Error Unfortunately app has stopped. if anyone have solution please give me  suggestion.
This  project is made on  eclipse but when i build on android studio it is not run properly give run time error.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;
               at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:164)
               at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:92)
               at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:79)
               at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:61)
               at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:97)
               at com.dhariyat.androidmapapp.nearby.GooglePlaces.search(GooglePlaces.java:42)
               at com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder.Activity_Nearby$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(Activity_Nearby.java:309)
               at com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder.Activity_Nearby$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(Activity_Nearby.java:277)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:164)
            at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:92)
            at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:79)
            at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:61)
            at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:97)
            at com.dhariyat.androidmapapp.nearby.GooglePlaces.search(GooglePlaces.java:42)
               at com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder.Activity_Nearby$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(Activity_Nearby.java:309)
               at com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder.Activity_Nearby$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(Activity_Nearby.java:277)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Preconditions
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 15 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
02-27 18:39:33.940    3019-3043/? E/ReportTools﹕ This is not beta user build
02-27 18:39:34.060    3019-3165/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '188113ab com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder/com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder.Activity_Near_Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

This is my code in which some issue occur.
 This  is my project libraries

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nearbyplaces.mapfinder"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    }

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you did not define a method for your button onclick task or the parameters you have defined in your async task method is wrong ... recheck if u have properly defined your onclick method in your java class